# RadioGroup on click fails

Tags: java, android, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I have set up a radio group dynamically like this:

**In my XML I have:**

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/user_accounts_radios"
       android:layout_gravity="left"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">
```

**In my Java code, I have**

```
RadioGroup radioGroup;
protected void onCreate(){
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.user_accounts_radios);
    setupUsers();
}
```

on the setupUsers

```
void displayOpts(){
    List<UserAccountDetailsModel> accounts = userAccountDetailsSqliteModel.getAccounts();

    RadioGroup account_radios = new RadioGroup(this);
    account_radios.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (UserAccountDetailsModel user : accounts){
        CompanyLocationsModel company = companyLocationSqliteModel.getCompany(user.getCompany_id());
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
        rdbtn.setTextSize(17);
        rdbtn.setId(company.getId());
        rdbtn.setText(user.getFirst_name() + " "+user.getLast_name() + " ---- " + company.getName());
        account_radios.addView(rdbtn);
    }
    radioGroup.addView(account_radios);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
           // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            Log.i("test", "Checked is "+checkedId);
        }
    });
}
```

The above displays the `RadioGroup` but I have the following issues:

> 1. Whenever I click on the second `RadioButton` the first one cannot be clicked
>      again
> 2. the log on the selected listener doesn't log

I dont know what is wrong, because the `RadioButtons` are displayed correctly.

Comment: Why you are creating another `RadioGroup` and why don't you add your all `RadioButton` directly inside your main `radioGroup`

Comment: Why do you add one `RadioGroup` into another? remove this `RadioGroup account_radios = new RadioGroup(this);` add all in `radioGroup` and try again.

Comment: @YaroslavOvdiienko thanks this now works I see my stupid error

Comment: That's OK, next time just think consistently and keep a code clean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `RadioGroup` which you put into the existing one. This is wrong. Just use the existing one like this:

```
void displayOpts(){
    List<UserAccountDetailsModel> accounts = userAccountDetailsSqliteModel.getAccounts();
    //deleted line
    //next line changed
    radioGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (UserAccountDetailsModel user : accounts){
        CompanyLocationsModel company = companyLocationSqliteModel.getCompany(user.getCompany_id());
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
        rdbtn.setTextSize(17);
        rdbtn.setId(company.getId());
        rdbtn.setText(user.getFirst_name() + " "+user.getLast_name() + " ---- " + company.getName());
        //next line changed
        radioGroup.addView(rdbtn);
    }
    //deleted line
    //next line changed
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
           // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            Log.i("test", "Checked is "+checkedId);
        }
    });
}
```